# Sum numbers that occur before character in a string except the immediately preceding number

Tags: r, regex

I have a number of strings (CIGARs) that I am trying to sum the numbers that occur before the number preceding `"I"`. The position that `"I"` occurs is highly variable but always has a number before it.
Here is a sample df:

```
df <- data.frame(String = c("220M1I","10I200M","5M2D1I20M","22M5D2M3I5M"))
```

My desired output looks like:

```
       String Sum_prior
1      220M1I       220
2     10I200M         0
3   5M2D1I20M         7
4 22M5D2M3I5M        29
```

I have a partial solution which can't handle >1 digit numbers prior to `"I"` which is problematic.

```
    sum_fun <- function(x) {
  str_match_all(x, "\\d+(?!I)") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    as.numeric() %>% 
    sum()
}
```

then applying to df:

```
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(output = sum_fun(String))
df



  String      output
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 220M1I         220 #Good
2 10I200M        201 #The 1 in 10 is being included
3 5M2D1I20M       27 #Don't want last 20 included
4 22M5D2M3I5M     34 #Don't want last 5 included
```

But I can't figure out how to adapt the regex to ignore all numbers immeadiately prior to `"I"` and sum all other numbers before `"I"`.

A more advanced example I need (but less important), is to calculate the cumulative number when there is more than one `"I"` - the first occurrence is as above (output_1), but the second (or more) (output_2) example includes the preceeding `"I"` number.

```
df2 <- data.frame(String =c("5M10I200M20I","100M2D3I105M1I10M")


             String Output_1 Output_2
1      5M10I200M20I        5      215
2 100M2D3I105M1I10M      102      210
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R approach:

```r
df <- data.frame(String = c("220M1I","10I200M","5M2D1I20M","22M5D2M3I5M"))
x <- sub("\\d+I.*$", "", df$String)
df$Sum_prior <- sapply(strsplit(x, "\\D"), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y)))
df

       String Sum_prior
1      220M1I       220
2     10I200M         0
3   5M2D1I20M         7
4 22M5D2M3I5M        29
```

The strategy here is to first strip off the number followed by `I`, until the end of the string.  Then, we string split on non numeric digits, to generate a vector of string numbers.  Finally, we sum those numbers to get the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to extract all the numbers followed by characters and `sum` the numbers before the occurrence of `'I'`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

sum_fun <- function(x) {
  tmp <- str_match_all(x, "(\\d+)[A-Z]+")[[1]]
  sum(as.numeric(tmp[, 2])[seq_len(grep('I', tmp[, 1]) - 1)])
}

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(output = sum_fun(String)) %>%
  ungroup

#  String      output
#  <chr>        <dbl>
#1 220M1I         220
#2 10I200M          0
#3 5M2D1I20M        7
#4 22M5D2M3I5M     29
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` plus `stringr` approach in one line:

```
(library(stringr)
df$Sum <- lapply(str_extract_all(sub("\\d+I.*$", "", df$String), "\\d+"), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
       String Sum
1      220M1I 220
2     10I200M   0
3   5M2D1I20M   7
4 22M5D2M3I5M  29
```

This works in steps:

- the first is the `sub`operation which gets rid of the single digit plus `I`plus the rest
- the second is the `str_extract_all` part which extracts all remaining digits into a list
- the third is the `lapply` part where we perform the mathematical operation on the listed digits

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `dplyr`, `stringr`, and `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)                                   
df %>%
  # Steps 1 (remove irrelevant part of string) and 2 (extract numbers): 
  mutate(String_new = str_extract_all(sub("\\d+I.*$", "", String), "\\d+")) %>%
  # Step 3: convert to numeric and perform calculation:
  mutate(String_new = map_dbl(String_new, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))
       String String_new
1      220M1I        220
2     10I200M          0
3   5M2D1I20M          7
4 22M5D2M3I5M         29
```